# How to remove `raspi-copies-and-fills` from Raspbian

Tags: raspbian-stretch, apt, packages

I did `apt update && apt upgrade` as root and now my Raspbian system is corrupt and won't boot anymore. After some debugging I noticed there's the package `raspi-copies-and-fills`.

Fortunately, my Pi isn't damaged, only the system is corrupt (verified by booting fresh Raspbian on my spare microSD cards). I want to recover this system, is it possible?

I have both Windows and Ubuntu at hand and microSD card readers, which I suppose should be up for a recovery job.

Comment: Just restore from the backup you made before upgrade

Comment: @Milliways I don't have backup. I flashed fresh Raspbian to spare SD cards just for verifying that the hardware isn't damaged.

Comment: @Milliways - that makes me laugh every time - it'd be nice if such a backup didn't take 30 minutes or more, or require removing the SD card from the pi to do it quicker :p

Comment: @JaromandaX It only takes 15 minutes to image a 16GB card, but there are other backup strategies (including SD Card Copier to duplicate a SD Card). The recovery method, listed in the Answer, often works but I am amazed by the users who claim to have valuable data but no backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Put the sd card into a card reader in Ubuntu system
- Now the tricky part is finding the device in Ubuntu, it could be `/dev/sdb` or something like that - one way to determine is to check the output of `dmesg`, you should see a message regarding the new device being attached
- assuming it's `/dev/sdb`:
- Repair the second partiton with `e2fsck -f /dev/sdb2`
- Then mount this partition: `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt`
- Then run `sudo rm /mnt/etc/ld.so.preload`
- And `sudo umount /dev/sdb2`

`/etc/ld.so.preload` contains /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so. This is the only significant file in `raspi-copies-and-fills` package.

Now insert the sd card back into the pi, and when you've booted, you can `apt update && apt upgrade` again since the offending package has been upgraded again and should now NOT break your pi

Comment: Why deleting `/mnt/etc/ld.so.preload`? For what is this file used? On my RasPi it doesn't contain anything about `raspi-copies-and-fills`.

Comment: Mine contains `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so` ... this is the only significant file in `raspi-copies-and-fills` package

Comment: yeah, I probably should've mentioned that in the answer @Ingo - otherwise it may look like I'm trying to do something nefarious :p thanks for the edit